# How to write subquery in select statement in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am trying to do an select with sub-queries using hive.

In foos table have the following columns:

```
foo1,
foo2,
foo3_input
```

**Is what I want**

```
select foo1, foo2, foo3 from foos;
```

**Is what I will execute**

```
select foo1, foo2, foo3_input from foos;
```

**for each foo3 in a row I would like to execute the following query**

```
foo3 = select bar1 from bars where (foo3_input) between val1 and val2;
```

Is there any possible way to construct this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hive version 0.13.0

```
select
    a.foo1, 
    a.foo2,
    b.bar1
from foos a, bars b
where a.foo3_input between b.val1, b.val2;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
select
    a.foo1, 
    a.foo2,
    b.bar1
from
(
    (select foo1, foo2, foo3_input from foos) a
    left outer join
    (select bar1, foo3_input from bars ) b
    on a.foo3_input = b.foo3_input
 )tmp
 where b.foo3_input between a.foo1, a.foo2
 ;
```

[edit]

```
select
    a.foo1, 
    a.foo2,
    b.bar1
from
(
    (select foo1, foo2, foo3_input from foos) a
    full outer join
    (select bar1, val1, var2 from bars ) b

 )tmp
 where a.foo3_input between b.val1, b.val2
 ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @JimmyZhang. foo3_input doesn’t belongs to bars table.

Comment: Could you show me the structure of table bars? @brisk

Comment: In bars table have the following columns bar1, bar2, val1, val2

Comment: @brisk, I change my answer, with full outer join.But the full outer join operation may time-consuming.

Comment: Got Error: FAILED: ParseException line 4:9 cannot recognize input near '(' 'SELECT' 'foo1' in subquery source.

Answer (score 1):

"Hive does not support IN, EXISTS or subqueries in the WHERE clause."
See this `https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-1799`

See this for where clause in hive `https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SubQueries#LanguageManualSubQueries-SubqueriesintheWHEREClause`

Comment: Thanks for your links! Can you give me any ideas to solve the above problem?